# Designing Curved Containers/CardViews in android Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-cardview

HI im currently trying to achieve something similar to the given image.
can anyone guide me through how can I get the look in Kotlin/xml view?
Part I need to design is the Price Tag view.

much appreciated

[image]

Comment: `CardView` containing `RelativeLayout` containing two childs: `ImageView` for picture and `TextView` for price. firt one fulfil parent (`match_parent`), second one aligned to bottom/right. thats very basic layout, accurate for some Android learning...

Comment: I have no issue in getting the layout. the part I need is that curved out look in the price tag

Answer (score 0):

If I were to implement it, I would

1. customize a textView (let's call it, curvedTextView). Perhaps inside onDraw method, I would draw a background that resemblances the carved part (the background of 15,000). Some coordinate geometry would do the trick. The shape lools like a tangent curve, exponential curve, or simply 2 circles with a common tangent... just pick one.
2. Once you have your view, simply use constraintlayout, imageView, and place the curvedTextView to bottomRignt corner.

I need to write some codes, and do some trials to come up with a sample code. I'll try to update the answer later. Sorry for the inconvenience.

## Update

So after writing some codes, here is my curvedTextView

```kotlin
package com.applications.ui

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat
import ridmik.one.R

class CurvedTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {
    val TAG = "CurvedTextView"

    val white = ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.resources, R.color.colorSolidWhite, null)
    val transparentColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.resources, R.color.transparent, null)

    val paint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        this.color = white
        this.style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE
    }
    val path: Path = Path()


    val paddingVertical: Float = getPxFromDp(context, 10.0).toFloat()
    val paddingHorizontal: Float = getPxFromDp(context, 20.0).toFloat()

    val delta: Float = getPxFromDp(context, 10.0).toFloat()  // random trial and error
    init{
    }

    fun getPxFromDp(context: Context, dp: Double): Double {
        return dp * context.resources.displayMetrics.density
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        if(canvas!=null) {
            path.moveTo(paddingHorizontal+delta, 0f)
            path.cubicTo(
                (paddingHorizontal - delta), delta,
                delta, height - delta,
                0f, height.toFloat()
            )
            path.lineTo(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
            path.lineTo(width.toFloat(), 0f)
            path.lineTo(paddingHorizontal+delta, 0f)

            canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        }
        super.draw(canvas)
    }

}
```

Now simply add inside your constraintLayout:

```kotlin
<ImageView
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>

    <com.applications.ui.CurvedTextView
    android:id="@+id/curvedTextView"
    android:text="$ 15,000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Output:
[image]

Now that you have the view, try tweaking the variables to make it precisely like your requirement.

Comment: I am trying to find my way through the 1. step you mentioned.

Comment: Hello, I wrote some codes, and then I updated my answer. So now you have the step 1. Please check it.

Comment: thank you so much for the amazing input. I think  there is a good limitation in android on achieving complex shapes.

Comment: Well, I see it as a geometry problem. In this sense, all you need to do is to define your shape mathematically. You can have certain benifits, such as, the shape won't overlap with your text (the price tag in this case). Using drawable background from photoshop may not guarantee that, so you may get some overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you can use any graphic software to draw the text background maybe `photoshop` or `adobe illustrator` for vectors. I'm not very good at this software but I created a vector image that is quite similar to what we actually want.

So in your `drawables` directory create a new drawable file, call it `tv_bg.xml`, then copy-paste this vector drawable.

### tv_bg.xml

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportWidth="196.739"
    android:viewportHeight="101.01">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M196.736,0.01L196.736,99.993L0,99.993s8.6,11.826 15.051,-45.153 93.532,-54.829 93.532,-54.829Z" />
</vector>
```

After that create a layout file, I called it `my_layout.xml`.

### my_layout.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image_placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$ 15.00"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/tv_bg"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And that will be your final result
[image: Final result]

Of course, you need to improve the `TextView` background and text style a little to match what you actually want.

Comment: I can try this out :)